# How to put an icon right next to an h1 text?

Tags: html, css, icons

I am trying to put an icon right near my h1 text, to the left of it. The h1 that says "Creative Writing" is the one I am targeting. I want the icon lined up with the h1 "creative writing".

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1qtq58y/

HTML:

```
<section id="main_sectiontwo">
    <h1>Creative Writing</h1>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>SESSION I (Writing for the Stage)</h1><br/>
        </header>
        <p>Whether a play or a musical, writing for the stage brings with it a unique set of challenges. Your script must not only have the story but also dialog, stage direction and a general sense of what is possible in a Theatre. Find out from someone who knows how it's done.</p>
        <p>Presenter: Bill Wright</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#main_sectiontwo article{
width:450px;
}

#main_sectiontwo{
height:1000px;
}

#main_sectiontwo article header{
color:#2754a2;
font-family:helvetica;
}

#main_sectiontwo article p{
font-family:arial;
}
```

Comment: can you pleas post a fiddle too..

Comment: if your logo size is more than your heading...read this http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/ it will help you for proper alignment of heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following style and it worked in chrome.

```
h1::before{
content: url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/be932e44c7d573abccf8bb844c79302d?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/79vh7ycu/1/)

### Edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/g1qtq58y/1/) too

I have used `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` tags

**HTML**

```
section id="main_sectiontwo">
<fieldset>
    <legend><h1><img src="yourimage" height="15" width="15"/>Creative Writing</h1></legend>
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>SESSION I (Writing for the Stage)</h1><br/>
        </header>
            <p>Whether a play or a musical, writing for the stage brings with it a unique set of challenges. Your script must not only have the story but also dialog, stage direction and a general sense of what is possible in a Theatre. Find out from someone who knows how it's done.</p>
            <p>Presenter: Bill Wright</p>
    </article>

    </fieldset>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#main_sectiontwo article{
width:450px;
}

#main_sectiontwo{
height:1000px;
}

#main_sectiontwo article header{
color:#2754a2;
font-family:helvetica;
}

#main_sectiontwo article p{
font-family:arial;
}
fieldset{
    border:none;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add the icon as a background-image to the h1 tag itself, and then add left-padding equal to the icon width + the actual padding you'd like to have avaialable.

A more scalable approach would be to add the icon to a custom font file and add an element to the  prior to the .  This would allow for a scaling vector image and proportionate em-based padding between the icon and the text.